# awk : print two Fields with seperate number

Tags: awk

I am new to unix and required some help...

I have a file with contents like:

```
119000 ABC/CSD/NEW/PB/PB1234_PB0001123.CSV
60000 ABC/CSD/NEW/PB/PB14567_PB0001123.CSV
25000 ABC/CSD/NEW/PB/VV/PB16734_PB0001123.CSV
80000 ABC/CSD/NEW/PB/VV/PB2314_PB09820123.CSV
33117 ABC/CSD/NEW/PB/VV/PB45634_PB0001123.CSV
```

I want output like:

```
119000 PB1234  PB0001123
60000 PB14567 PB0001123 
25000 PB16734 PB0001123 
80000 PB2314  PB09820123 
33117 PB45634 PB0001123
```

Sorted by second field and then by third field...

Comment: please also add what you've tried to question... see [how much research effort is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: also, create a sample where sorting makes a difference... given ip/op are in same order..

Answer (score 3):

If your actual Input_file is same as shown sample then following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F'[ /_.]' '{print $1,$(NF-2),$(NF-1)}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

`-F'[ /_.]'`: `-F` is used in `awk` for setting delimiter for lines. So here we are setting (space),`/`,`_` and `.` as field separators for any line for mentioned(passed) Input_file.

`print $1,$(NF-2),$(NF-1)`: Using `awk`'s out of the box command named `print` to print then `$1` mentions as first field value of current line, `$(NF-2)` mentions 3rd last field value of current line `$(NF-1)` indicates 2nd last field value of the current line.

Comment: it provides the desired output ..with slight modification

Comment: awk -F'[/_.]' '{print $1,$(NF-2),$(NF-1)}'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
awk '{
       split($2,a,"/")              # Split the 2nd element into the array a
       split(a[length(a)],b,"[_.]") # Split the last element of the array into the array b
       print $1,b[1],b[2]           # Print the wanted string
    }' file
```